# FFmpeg Drawtext Fade Out Performance

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing an application that makes system calls to FFmpeg.

I found a way to get the drawtext filter isolated and fade out, but the render time increased about 5x.

I just want to see if there is something obviously wrong with the command I came up with.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0]scale=1920:1080,format=rgba, split[base][text];[text]drawtext=fontfile=font1.ttf:text='Text1':fontcolor= 'white':fontsize=34:box=1:boxcolor=mediumpurple:boxborderw=50:x=0:y=690,format=yuva444p,drawtext=fontfile=./resources/fonts/font2.ttf:text='Text2':fontcolor='white':fontsize=26:x=0:y=725,fade=t=out:st=12:d=0.2:alpha=1[title];[base][title]overlay" -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.05)" output.mp4
```

Comment: Copy and paste all of the text from the log.

Comment: Use the `alpha` option of drawtext. Remove the video split, fade out & overlay.  `-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.05)"` will force KF every 50 ms. Why?

Comment: @llogan https://pastebin.com/gviYSU0F

Comment: @Gyan I found my error, I mixed up where t should be in `between()`.
Now I am trying to add a smooth fade out with `lerp()`

Comment: @Gyan The key frame thing was put in there by a colleague. I believe it made it easier when later processing the video again for generating GL Transitions between clips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There is something obviously wrong with it. There is no need to split the stream and process both.

After some trial and error, I was able to put together this command which runs much much faster; virtually no overhead to add the fading title card.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "scale=1920:1080,drawtext=fontfile=font1.ttf:text=Text1':fontcolor='white':fontsize=34:box=1:boxcolor=mediumpurple:boxborderw=50:x=12:y=690:alpha='min(between(t,0,2.2),lerp(0,1,(1+((2-t)/0.2))))',drawtext=fontfile=font2.ttf:text='Text2':fontcolor='white':fontsize=26:x=12:y=730:alpha='min(between(t,0,2.2),lerp(0,1,(1+((2-t)/0.2))))'" output.mp4
```

Comment: @llogan It is indeed! Thanks!